# How to optimize Dockerfile for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, docker

I would like my Dockerfile to create an image with Oracle and my database.
The image will be used for integration testing during the build.
So it should be small and fast.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM valspace/oracle:18.4.0-xe

# Environment variables required for this build (do NOT change)
# -------------------------------------------------------------
ENV ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle \
    ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE \
    ORACLE_SID=XE \
    PATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

# download my.dmp
ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD
RUN yum install curl
RUN curl -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" https://myrepo/my.dmp -o /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my.dmp

RUN chmod a+rxw /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my.dmp

# copy initialization scripts
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ADD script.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

script.sh:

```
impdp system/oracle DUMPFILE=/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my.dmp
```

init.sql:

```
--  Creates:
--  tablespaces ...
--  users...

EXIT
```

Problems with the scripts:

1. Files like.DMP, .SH, .SQL inside of the final image.
2. It creates the image that imports DMP file on every start-up. Instead, it should do it during the build-time.
3. Is it possible to run Oracle in a minimal configuration?

Comment: The database doesn't start at build time, so dmp and sql files wouldn't get read. If they did, then the image wouldn't be small as you'd then have both those files and the database server storage files in the container... If you don't want the dmp, sql, sh files in the container, use a volume mount instead

Comment: I want database to start at build time, import the DMP file, and get rid of it. Stop database.

Comment: I understand what you want, but my point was that that would create a potentially large Docker image, and wouldn't be "optimized"